# Win+Space keyboard shortcut doesn't work for me in Windows 7. Why?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

I have read several Windows 7 keyboard shortcut blog posts and guides and several of them mention that <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> should make all windows transparent revealing the desktop.

I'm running Windows 7 and this keyboard shortcut doesn't work for me. Is there something I have to do to enable it?

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> does take me to the desktop so that's pretty helpful, but I would really like to get <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> working.

[image]

Update: Looks like it is disabled for some reason.

These are my Visual Effects settings:

[image]
I have confirmed that my hardware meets the Aero Experience requirements and that it is enabled. I did have to change my theme from a custom theme to an Aero theme. I did that and rebooted and still have the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have to keep the key combination pressed for it to work.

Please note, hovering with your mouse cursor over the highlighted button should result in the same effect.
[image]
It won't work on this desktop, as Aero is disabled.

To enable Aero, make sure you select one of the Aero themes in the Personalization window:
[image]

If you have Aero enabled, but it still won't work. Check this setting:
[image]

Aero Peek also has to be enabled separately (if not enabled yet):
[image]

Comment: If that still doesn't help, please notice the link that says *Troubleshoot problems with transparency and other Aero effects* in the last screenshot. Sometimes it helps.

Comment: How long do I have to keep it pressed? I tried for 10 seconds. No luck. All the other Aero stuff works (Win-Tab to show card stack of windows and switch between apps, etc).

Comment: 10 seconds is more than enough for sure. Half a second should be fine in fact. But the windows are only transparent while you keep the keys pressed.

Comment: I added additional information that might relate better to your specific issue. Hope it helps :)

Comment: The windows are only transparent while the *win key is pressed*. Releasing space and keeping win down keeps the windows transparent.

Answer (score 1):

Enable the Windows Aero Experience, for this you have to meet the following requirements:

- DirectX 9 compatible GPU with a minimum of 128 MB of Video RAM
- You also have to have its driver installed which should be a WDDM driver
- 1 GHz 32-bit (x86) or 64-bit (x64) processor
- 1 GB (gigabyte) of RAM

Once you meet the requirements open the start menu and type the following:
"Find and fix problems with transparency and other visual effects"

Then click on the link with that name. See the screenshot below.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Aero Experience was already enabled. Ran the troubleshooter and it did not find any problems.